# Calculations precision level in R

Tags: r, precision

I am working in `R` with very small numbers which reflect probabilities in an Maximum Likelihood Estimation algorithm. Some of these numbers are as small as 1e-155 ( or smaller). However, when there is something as simple as summation taking place, the precision level gets truncated to the least precise one and thus ruins the precisions of my calculations and produces meaningless results.

Example:

```
    > sum(c(7.831908e-70,6.002923e-26,6.372573e-36,5.025015e-38,5.603268e-38,1.118121e-14,  4.512098e-07,4.400717e-05,2.300423e-26,1.317602e-58))
    [1] 4.445838e-05
```

As is seen from the example, the base for this calculation is 1e-5 , which in a very rude manner rounds up sensitive calculation.

Is there a way around this? Why is `R` choosing such a strange automatic behavior? Perhaps it is not really doing this, I just see the result in the truncated form? In this case, is the actual number with correct precision stored in the variable?

Comment: `options(digits = 22)` should give you up to 22 digits (then run your calculation), and from what I can tell this is highest it can go in the base package

Comment: higher precision is fine, but you should spend a little bit of time thinking about whether it's meaningful in the context of the problem you're doing.  If you're adding a probability of 10^{-70} to one of 10^{-5}, under what circumstances is it actually going to matter if the smaller probability is lost due to lack of numerical precision ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker,this is exactly the reason I am trying to understand how R does calculations. Sometimes I have to take a very small number to a very big power ( say, 1e-17) taken to power of,say, 20.. `R` actually goes as far as giving me an answer to the power in triple digits (such as 1e-150 or even smaller). I wonder how does `R` even display result to this precision. I guess the issue is: how long can the number be displayed as ( say, 5.5555555555555555e-5) vs what is the most precise **digit**, such as 5e-320.What I see is `R`,after creating such small number,seems to 'ignore' it further on.

Comment: You should probably read up a little bit on floating-point representations.  There is a difference between the number of digits of precision and the absolute magnitude of a number that can be represented ...

Comment: @BenBolker, will do. I guess do I have a bit of unclarity when it comes to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no precision loss in your sum. But if you're worried about it, you should use a multiple-precision library:

```
library("Rmpfr")

x <- c(7.831908e-70,6.002923e-26,6.372573e-36,5.025015e-38,5.603268e-38,1.118121e-14,  4.512098e-07,4.400717e-05,2.300423e-26,1.317602e-58)

sum(mpfr(x, 1024))

# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  1024   bits 
# [1] 4.445837981118120898327314579322617633703674840117902103769961398533293289165193843930280422747754618577451267010103975610356319174778512980120125435961577770470993217990999166176083700886405875414277348471907198346293122011042229843450802884152750493740313686430454254150390625000000000000000000000000000000000e-5
```

Comment: I have added a comment to the conversation above.. Just to con

Answer (score 7):

Your results are only truncated in the display.

Try:

```
x <- sum(c(7.831908e-70,6.002923e-26,6.372573e-36,5.025015e-38,5.603268e-38,1.118121e-14,  4.512098e-07,4.400717e-05,2.300423e-26,1.317602e-58))

print(x, digits=22)
[1] 4.445837981118121081878e-05
```

You can read more about the behaviour of print at `?print.default`

---

You can also set an option - this will affext all calls to `print`

```
options(digits=22)
```

Comment: I have accepted the first answer because it allows me to go with more precision than 22 digits, however I found this answer also very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

have you ever heard about Floating point numbers?
there is no loss of precision (significant figures) in multiplication or division as far as the result stay between 
`1.7976931348623157·10^308 to 4.9·10^−324`     (see the link for detail)

so if you do `1.0e-30 * 1.0e-10` result will be `1.0e-40`

but if you do `1.0e-30 + 1.0e-10` result will be `1.0e-10`

Why?

-> finite set of number rapresentable with computer works. (64 bits max 2^64 different representation of numbers with 64 bits)

instead of using a direct conversion like for integer numbers (they represent `from ~ -2^62 to +2^62`, every INTEGER number -> about `from -10^16 to +10*16`)
or there exist a clever way like floating point? from `1.7976931348623157·10^308 to - 4.9·10^−324` and it can represent /approximate rational numbers?

So in floating point, to achieve a wider range, precision in sums is sacrified, There is loss of precision during sums or subtractions as the significant figures that could be represented by (the 52 bits of) the fraction part (of a floating point number of 64 bits) are less than `log10(2^52) ~ 16`.
if you look for a basic everyday example, summary(lm), when the p-value of parameter is near zero, summary() output <2.2e-16 (what a coincidence).

why limited to 64 bits? CPU have the execution units specifically to 64bits floating point arithmetic (64 bit IEEE 754 standard), if you use higher precision like 128 bits floating point, the performances will be lowered by 10 times or more, as CPU need to split the data and operation in multiple 64 bits data and operations.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format